# UILabel внутри UITableviewcell отображается только при нажатии

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, tableview

я создал `tableview` и `tableviewcell` внутри которого поместил `label`, после запуска кастомные `uilabel` отображаются только при нажатии на ячейку. как сделать чтобы они отображались постоянно?

[image: окно xcode]

код

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
{
    NSMutableArray *tableData;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    tableData= [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"vlad",@"vlad2", nil];
    [tableData addObject:@"dddd"];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.

}

- (NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return tableData.count;
}



- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simple=@"BaseCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell= [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simple];
    cell.textLabel.text=[tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    UILabel *sub;
    sub=(UILabel *)[[cell contentView] viewWithTag:1];
    sub.text=@"asd";//[NSString stringWithFormat:[tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row],@"2222"];
    [sub text];
    sub.textColor=[UIColor greenColor];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    return cell;
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 70.0;
}

@end
```

результат в симуляторе

[image: симулятор]

Comment: а что это за хак с нахождением вью по тэгу?

Comment: Я новичок в этом. Но по тегу находит и кое-как работает ) а как можно по другому найти?

Comment: а что вы ищете?

Comment: Там ищется label(у него стоит тег - 1) который находится в прототипе ячейки BaseCell, он находится, изменяется кодом на asd, но проблема в том что в симуляторе этот label виден только при выделении ячейки. Надо как-то это исправить

Comment: смотрите ответ ниже - должен помочь

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте создать класс для ячейки и добавьте в него аутлет для вашей метки, потом в коде меняйте значение метки в методе `cellForRowAtIndexPath()`.
Это наиболее правильный путь. Только не забудьте поменять класс ячейки с дефолтового на ваш.
На скриншоте не видно, какой именно стиль ячейки вы выбрали. Должен быть `custom`. В вашем коде вы присваиваете значение для дефолтовой метки, а не для то что вы вставили в *IB*, если стиль `default` то возможно такое поведение как у вас. Что метку не видно без нажатия.

P.S. А еще советую убрать из вашего кода добавление значения для `cell.TextLabel` Тогда ваша метка должна отображаться нормально. А так вы смешиваете кастомный стиль с дефолтовым.